# Internet Explorer stuttering requests

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

For a special project I chose to write my very own tiny web server which is actually quite easy with the .Net Framework (HttpListener class).

Everything was working beautifully until yesterday when I started to test with Internet Explorer.

My server kept crashing on any ie request ! I finally managed to figure the reason out : ie litterally stutters ! (well at least ie7 and ie8, I've not tried other versions yet).

The problem never occurs with FireFox nor Chrome nor Opera.

To be more specific, I'm using dynamic javascript insertion in the web page to get around the same origin policy in a cross-domain call scenario. This script generates a request to my tiny server. Let's say the request built is :

```
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,p4=D,p5=E
```

With FFox, Chrome or Opera, my server indeed receives a single request from the browser :

```
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,p4=D,p5=E
```

with ie, my server receives a random amount of partial requests like :

```
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,p4=D,
```

(and in fact a lot of them since I have 20 parameters or so...)

and finally :

```
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,p4=D,p5=E
```

This is bascically not big deal as my logic is able to handle the lacking parameters situation. The problem is that each incomplete request actually closes the connection (error 1229). That was crashing the server which was trying to answer to each request. The fix was easy but I still don't like the fact that the server is flooded with those intermediate "unanswerable" and thus unuseful requests.
(Moreover, the request sometimes looks like :

```
http://localhost:8081/myService?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,?p1=A,p2=B,p3=C,p4=D,p5=E
```

!!! )

I traced the javascript : the generation function is called only once (whatever browser) so this really sounds like an ie issue.

Does anyone have an idea to prevent this behaviour from ie ?

Comment: You are using `,` as delimiter instead of the commonly seen `&` for some special reason?

Comment: felt like it was more "human-readable"... No other reason...Just changed it in code. It obviously has no effect.